# lseek EOVERFLOW error handling

Tags: c, linux, file, system-calls, errno

I've noticed that when I try to seek more bytes than off_t can represent I get
an EOVERFLOW error.
How can I seek more than the bigger number in off_t?

Comment: Are you working in a 32-bit environment where `off_t` is a 32-bit signed type?  And then you're trying to seek to a position more than 2 GiB through a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable [large file support](http://www.suse.de/~aj/linux_lfs.html).

> In a nutshell for using LFS you can choose either of the following:
>
> - Compile your programs with "`gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`". This forces all file access calls to use the 64 bit variants. Several types change also, e.g. `off_t` becomes `off64_t`. It's therefore important to always use the correct types and to not use e.g. `int` instead of `off_t`. For portability with other platforms you should use `getconf LFS_CFLAGS` which will return `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` on Linux platforms but might return something else on e.g. Solaris. For linking, you should use the link flags that are reported via `getconf LFS_LDFLAGS`. On Linux systems, you do not need special link flags.
> - Define `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` and `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`. With these defines you can use the LFS functions like open64 directly.
> - Use the `O_LARGEFILE` flag with `open` to operate on large files.

Comment: +1 for correctness and completeness, but the only approach anybody should be doing in 2012 is the first one.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/lseek64.3.html